# How to import javascript files to use with Vue-Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I would like to know what is the correct way to import javascript files in my entire Vue project, also include in the components that I use to make the changes with Vue-Router, that my current problem is that I have to reload the component so that the Javascript is load in each one, that is, if I change the Route and therefore of component, the Javascript functions only work when doing F5 in each one, and the Router Link is not enough, I suppose it is because I am not including them in the way correct and the Router View does not load the Javascript in each component according to the route.

This is my `index.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>vue-sfi</title>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/Plugins/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Tempusdominus Bbootstrap 4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/Plugins/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css">
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/Plugins/plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- JQVMap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/Plugins/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/Public/css/material.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/Plugins/dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
    <!-- overlayScrollbars -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/Plugins/plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css">
    <!-- Daterange picker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/Plugins/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
    <!-- summernote -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/Plugins/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/Public/css/styleSGB.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/Public/css/aside.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/Public/css/tables.css">
    <!-- Ion Slider -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/Plugins/plugins/ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css">
    <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="./static/Plugins/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
  <script src="./static/Plugins/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
  <script>
    $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
    ;
  </script>
  <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
  <script src="./static/Plugins/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <!-- ChartJS -->
  <script src="./static/Plugins/plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Sparkline -->
  <script src="./static/Plugins/plugins/sparklines/sparkline.js"></script>
  <!-- JQVMap -->
  <script src="./static/Plugins/plugins/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./static/Plugins/plugins/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.usa.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
  <script src="./static/Plugins/plugins/jquery-knob/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>
  <!-- daterangepicker -->
  <script src="./static/Plugins/plugins/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./static/Plugins/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
  <!-- Tempusdominus Bootstrap 4 -->
  <script src="./static/Plugins/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Summernote -->
  <script src="./static/Plugins/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.js"></script>
  <!-- overlayScrollbars -->
  <script src="./static/Plugins/plugins/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.min.js"></script>
  <!-- AdminLTE App -->
  <script src="./static/Plugins/dist/js/adminlte.js"></script>
  <!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
  <script src="./static/Plugins/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
  <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
  <script src="./static/Plugins/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Ion Slider -->
  <script src="./static/Plugins/plugins/ion-rangeslider/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my file structure in case you need to know that something is wrong:

```
/
    |--> index.html
    |-->  /src
    |     |--> /components    <----components Vue Router
    |     |    |--> /interfaces
    |     |    |    |--> /afiliacion
    |     |    |         |--> afiliacion.vue
    |     |    |--> /layouts
    |     |         |--> /modules
    |     |              |--> aside.vue
    |     |              |--> footer.vue
    |     |              |--> header.vue
    |     |--> /router
    |     |    |--> index.js <---- routes
    |     |--> App.vue
    |     |--> main.js
    |--> /static
         |--> /plugins <---- css and javascript files
         |--> /public  <---- css and javascript files.
```

This is the file for the routes.

```
import Afiliacion from '@/components/Interfaces/Afiliacion/Afiliacion.vue'
Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login,
      meta: {
        requiresVisitor: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/logout',
      name: 'Logout',
      component: Logout
    },
    {
      path: '/Home',
      name: 'Layout',
      component: Layout,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      },
      children:[
         {
      path: 'Interfaces/Afiliacion',
      redirect: '/Home/Afiliacion',
      name: 'Afiliaciones',
      component:{
        render (c){ return c('router-view') }
      },
      children: [
        {
          path: '/AfiliacionFondo',
          name: 'Afiliacion',
          component: Afiliacion,
          meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
          }
        }]
```

I have read that in the `src/assets` folder the CSS and Javascript should go, which is perhaps where I should place them, but I would like to help me please.

Comment: Why do you need jQuery if you are using vue? If you are using it just so you can use bootstrap consider using bootstrap-vue

Comment: Because I am using the AdminLTE template that is a dashboard, and uses jQuery, so I am interested in using these files

Comment: I answered your question, but i think that AdminLTE has a version for Vue without jQuery if not you should try a template that doesn't use jQuery. Is a matter of efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way of importing jQuery to vue project.

## install dependencies

npm install vue-jquery --save

## In the main.js file

import vue-jquery from 'vue-jquery'

Vue.use(vue-jquery)

You have to install with npm if you want to use external libraries in vue. Then you import it the same way i imported jQuery above.

## AdminLTE Vue

This is the Vue AdminLTE try it. Here you just have to execute npm i.

https://vuejsadmin.com/product/vue2-admin-lte/